# In Windows 10, WSL 2, Windows Terminal, bash and VIM, how to avoid the conflict of <c-v>?

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, visual-block

With the newly released Windows 10 update 2004, we can run native Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) 2 and install Ubuntu 20.04 on it.  Then we can run native bash inside the latest Windows Terminal.  However, when I run vim in it, I have trouble with vim's visual block selection: :

1. In this environment, both `<c-v>` and `<c-V>` are used for Windows Copy;
2. Since this vim is running in a "pure" linux environment, it has nothing to do with mswin.vim;
3. I tried `<c-q>` and it doesn't work;

What's the most organic solution for resolving this issue?  Is mapping a different key, like `<c-q>` acting as visual block selection the only one?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: (P.S. `<C-v>` and `<C-V>` are *probably* the same if the environment faithfully replicates terminal handling; the two are indistinguishable as key `0x16`.) What happens when you press `<C-q>`? If you haven't disabled control flow, it may not get to vim to start visual-block mode (`:help CTRL-V-alternative`)

Comment: Hi Ben Knoble, nothing happens when I press <C-q> in normal mode.  How can I disable the control flow then and what's the side effects of it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found to this problem is to comment out the lines in the Windows Terminal `settings.json` binding copy and paste to `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V` respectively. By default, they are bound to `Ctrl+Shift+C` and `Ctrl+Shift+V`.

```
 "keybindings":
    [
        // Copy and paste are bound to Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+Shift+V in your defaults.json.
        // These two lines additionally bind them to Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V.
        // To learn more about selection, visit https://aka.ms/terminal-selection
        // { "command": {"action": "copy", "singleLine": false }, "keys": "ctrl+c" },
        // { "command": "paste", "keys": "ctrl+v" },     

    ]
```